# Ruby: "if !object.nil?" or "if object"

Tags: ruby

Are they the same when used in an `if/else/end` statement? What do you usually do? I'm wondering if there are any subtle differences or edge cases where `object` and `!object.nil?` would respond differently.

Comment: Isn't the ruby way to write `if object.nil?.!` ;-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are differences. For example:

```
false.nil?
# => false
```

So:

```
if !false.nil?
  'foo'
end
# => "foo"

if false
  'foo'
end
# => nil
```

As @tokland suggested, in most cases using `!obj.nil?` construction is unnecessary.

Comment: It may be worth adding to the answer that even though the `false` case is indeed special, 99% of the time the sadly common `!obj.nil?` is unnecessary and non-declarative.

Comment: @tokland thanks for your suggestion. Feel free to edit my answer if you feel I didn't express it well.

Comment: some additional ones `!!nil => false` `!!object => true`. Also `nil.to_bool => false` and `object.to_bool => true`. But still not perfect. Maybe the language needs a `not_nil?` or `!nil?`

Comment: Edit made it clear to inattentive people, though "**There** [are differences]" is far **different** from "**They** [are differents]".

Answer (score 15):

There is one and only one case in which `!object.nil?` and `object` evaluate to different results in a boolean context and that is if `object` is `false`. In all other situations the result is the same.

With this, I think we can answer your real question (which is: Is there any situation where I must use `if !object.nil?` instead of just `if object` when protecting against `object` being nil?):

No, you can always use `if object` if you want to check against `nil`.

Answer (score 9):

`if object` tests if `object` isn't either `nil` or `false`.

`!object.nil?` tests if `object` isn't `nil`. [(Rubydoc)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F)

So when `object` is `false`, they have different values.

Answer (score 2):

Well. `if object` will behave differently from `if !object.nil?` if `object=false`.

That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Objects can override `nil?` but they cannot be falsely unless they are nil or false. Personally I use `nil?` or ActiveSupport's `present?` so that I maintain that flexibility. I also think it reads a bit better.